# Can a series of years be possessive?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Can a series of years be possessive? For example:

> I am 1990s' child

This feels weird, but is it technically correct? And how about the following?

> I am a child of the 1990s'

Comment: Genitive, not possessive.

Comment: There should be no apostrophe in the second variant.  And most Google hits on a search for ["a sixties phenomenon"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&ei=U9bsXoCgGsHMgwe2-ZzgBA&q=%22a+sixties+phenomenon%22&oq=%22a+sixties+phenomenon%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCCEQoAE6BQgAEJECOgUIABCxAzoFCAAQgwE6AggAOgcIABCxAxBDOgQIABBDOgQIABANOgYIABANEB46BggAEBYQHjoHCCEQChCgAVC7nhNY-ecTYNbrE2gBcAB4AIABbYgB5gySAQQyMS4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdperABAA&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjAlerKlY7qAhVB5uAKHbY8B0wQ4dUDCAk&uact=5) drop the apostrophe and use the plural attributive usage.

Comment: @Lawrence There's a difference?

Comment: Yes, _genitive_ can refer to close association that isn’t possessive.

Comment: So could "I am a 90's child" be correct because it's genitive instead of possessive?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, yes, one can write 'a sixties phenomenon' and so avoid the OP's dilemma, by not using the genitive at all. But what if one wants to use the genitive?

Comment: @jsw29 There's a growing lobby that one shouldn't.  Backed by usage. Similarly, there are far more clubs styling themselves 'X Working Mens Club', and examples of 'working mens club/s',  than there were in the sixties.

Answer (score -3):

I am 1990s' child (two errors)

I am **a** 1990's child. (the apostrophe here is not genitive, it indicates the plural)

---

I am a child of the 1990s' (one error)

I am a child of the 1990's  (again the apostrophe indicates the plural)

Comment: Greengrocer's apostophe's are anathema.

Comment: @ Andrew Leach - What is your point?

Comment: Apostophe's are not used for plural's. Writing *1990s* is enough.

Comment: I refer you to the followng link. It says: *There are different schools of thought about years and decades. The following examples are all in widespread use: 
Examples:
the 1990s
the 1990's
the '90s
the 90's*

Comment: (continued) The link is here https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp   See Rule 6.  Remember that apostrophes can also be used for abbreviations and omissions.

Comment: But 1990s is an ordinary plural, as you say yourself in your answer. I refer you to Rule 2b of your source.

Comment: I disagree. I don't mind if people use 1990s - It's a matter of style. However when a numeral is pluralised, it is not an 'ordinary plural'. It is an abbreviation. Also, if you wanted to ask the number of A's in "apple", would you write it as "the number of As in apple?".  "Potato's" is wrong but if a lazy greengrocer wanted to write "Po's" as an abbreviation, I wouldn't say it should be "Pos"

Comment: It's not an abbreviation: it's a plural, **and you have said so in your answer.** And yes, I would use *As* and not *A's* in your sentence.

Comment: It is both plural and an abbreviation. They are not mutually incompatible.

Comment: In that case **your answer is wrong** because you explicitly say it's the plural, and it's not.

Comment: How about "How many lowercase a's in apple?" Would you write "How many lowercase as in apple?" ? or simply How many as in apple?"

Comment: I would use "lowercase As" as you suggested earlier. But this is irrelevant. Your own source contradicts your answer.

Comment: I don't think that limited-text comments are useful for this discussion and we're getting off-topic. If you read Rule 6  in my source, it is clear that 1990's would be counted both as a plural and would, according to "some schools of thought", be suitable for apostrophizing. Maybe this should be the subject matter for a separate question. I have examined your reasoning and disagree. I wonder if you have read mine carefully.

Comment: P.S.  Here's one to chew on.* "I notice that A's have a pointy top whereas a's are rounded."*  How would you write that (without changing any of the wording)